# Finding the dominant eigenvalue of a symbolic matrix and simplifying it in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, symbolic-math, eigenvalue

I have the following symbolic matrix and I want to find its dominant eigenvalue using Matlab.

```
r = [               (c*r1)/(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p),                                    (c*r1)/(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p),                    (c*r1)/(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)]
    [ (a1*c*q*r2)/(d1*d5 + c*d4*d5 - d1*d5*p), (r2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p + a1*c*q))/(d1*d5 + c*d4*d5 - d1*d5*p),      (a1*c*q*r2)/(d1*d5 + c*d4*d5 - d1*d5*p)]
    [   (d1*p*r3)/(d1*d3 + c*d3*d4 - d1*d3*p),                        (d1*p*r3)/(d1*d3 + c*d3*d4 - d1*d3*p), (r3*(d1 + c*d4))/(d1*d3 + c*d3*d4 - d1*d3*p)]
```

To find the eigenvalues I used `simplify(eig(r))`, which produced very large expressions:

```
((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))/((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p))
((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))/(2*((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3)) - 3^(1/2)*((((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3)*1i)/2 + (((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))*1i)/(2*((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3))) - ((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3)/2 + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p))
((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))/(2*((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3)) + 3^(1/2)*((((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3)*1i)/2 + (((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))*1i)/(2*((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3))) - ((((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)) - (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^2/(9*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2))^3 + ((d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^2)^(1/2) + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)^3/(27*d3^3*d5^3*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^3) - ((d1*r2*r3 + c*d3*r1*r2 + c*d4*r2*r3 + c*d5*r1*r3 + a1*c*q*r2*r3)*(d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2))/(6*d3^2*d5^2*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)^2) + (c*r1*r2*r3)/(2*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p)))^(1/3)/2 + (d1*d3*r2 + d1*d5*r3 - d1*d3*p*r2 + c*d3*d4*r2 + c*d3*d5*r1 + c*d4*d5*r3 + a1*c*d3*q*r2)/(3*d3*d5*(d1 + c*d4 - d1*p))
```

How can I simplify these expressions and find the dominant eigenvalue?
Also, does this contain imaginary eigenvalues? If so, I can remove them from consideration.

Comment: As different real values are assigned to the symbols, the 3 eigenvalues will travel on the complex plane. I don't see how this question makes sense.